# Semidefiniteness of Quadratic form with zero determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms

Consider a function in quadratic form
$f=x^T A x$, where $x\in\mathbb R^2$.Let $\det A=0$.
(Therefore, one eigenvalue is zero. )

With the above assumption, how can it be shown that $f: x\mapsto f$ is $\geq0$ or $\leq 0$ for all $x$?

I assume that if $\lambda_1=0, \lambda_2>0$, $f\geq0$ and vice versa. But not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that since $f$ is a quadratic form, $A$ is symmetric. Assume $\lambda_1 \le \lambda_2$. By the [min-max theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem), we have

$$
\lambda_1 \le \frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx} \le \lambda_2\tag1
$$

for all non-zero $x$. Note that $x^Tx \ge 0$. There are two cases:

- $\lambda_1=0$ and $\lambda_2 \ge 0$,
- $\lambda_1 < 0$ and $\lambda_2 =0$.

We see from $(1)$ that in the first case $f(x)=x^TAx$ is non-negative for all $x$. Similarly, in the second case $f(x)$ is non-positive for all $x$.

---

The statement is not true if $A$ is not symmetric. Let

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}\quad u = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}\quad v = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Then

$$
f(u) = u^TAu = -1 \\
f(v) = v^TAv = 1.
$$

---

Also, the statement is not true in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n>2$ even if $A$ is symmetric. Counterexample: $A=\mathrm{diag}(1, -1, 0)$.